# How to attach click event on a specific DIV which is nested much

Tags: jquery, html

i have one child div which is nested much. i want when anyone will click on that div then i want to show a alert but if some one will click on out side of my specific nested div then my click event will not fire.

my specific div is `arrange_collection_today`

```
<div id="header_container" class="c12">
    <div id="header_content_big_empty" class="g12">
        <div class="warranty_rollover_position_relative_wrapper_header">
            <div class="arrange_collection_today">
              <span>Arrange Collection of your faulty part today!</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i try to solve it this way but got no luck

```
$('div').click(function(ev){
    var class_name = $(this).attr('class');
    if(class_name='arrange_collection_today')
    {
        alert('testing...');
    }
});
```

so please guide me how to achieve all. thanks

Comment: Why not just `$(".arrange_collection_today")`?

Comment: put `if(class_name=='arrange_collection_today')` instead of `if(class_name='arrange_collection_today')`

Comment: @tymeJV That should be an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

```
$('div').click(function(ev){
    if($(this).hasClass('arrange_collection_today'))
    {
        alert('testing...');
    }
});
```

Or Recommended

```
$(".arrange_collection_today").click(function() {

});
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6kzjLtf5/)

Answer (score 2):

You can always just use a more specific selector:

```
$(".arrange_collection_today").click(function() {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using JQuery then you can use the following

```
$(document).on("click", ".arrange_collection_today", function() { //code in here});
```

this has the advantage of firing on dynamically created elements as well as those present during the page load process.